# ANTLR 'or' regular expression

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar

I have a serious problem about `|` expression.

My grammar contains expression like this.

```
...ifelse : 'IF' condition 'THEN' dosomething+ 'ENDIF'
...dosomething : assign | print | input;
```

but `dosomething` becomes constant. For example :

```
IF a > 3 THEN
PRINT "HEllo"
b = a
ENDIF
```

so first `dosomething` is `print` and grammar can't read `assing, input`.

If statements become like this, it works correct

```
IF a > 3 THEN
PRINT "HEllo"
PRINT myName
ENDIF
```

So i mean 'or' `( | | )+` expression becomes constants same as first occured expression.

```
grammar hellog;

prog : command+;

command : maincommand
        | expressioncommand
        | flowcommand
        ;
//main
maincommand : printcommand
            | inputcommand
            ;

printcommand : 'PRINT' (IDINT | IDSTR | STRING) NL
             | 'PRINT' (IDINT | IDSTR | STRING) (',' (IDINT | IDSTR | STRING))* NL
             ;
inputcommand : 'INPUT' (IDINT | IDSTR) NL
             | 'INPUT' STRING? (IDINT | IDSTR) NL
             ;

//expression
expressioncommand : intexpression
                  | strexpression
                  ;
intexpression : IDINT '=' (IDINT | INT) NL
              | IDINT '=' (IDINT | INT) (OPERATORMATH (IDINT | INT))* NL
              ;
strexpression : IDSTR '=' (IDSTR | STRING) NL
              | IDSTR '=' (IDSTR | STRING) ('+' (IDSTR | STRING))* NL
              ;
//flow
flowcommand : ifelseflow
            | whileflow
            ;

ifelseflow : 'IF' conditionflow 'THEN' NL dosomething+ ('ELSEIF' conditionflow 'THEN' NL dosomething+)* ('ELSE' NL dosomething+)? 'ENDIF' NL;
whileflow : 'WHILE' conditionflow NL (dosomething)+ 'WEND' NL;
dosomething : command;
conditionflow : (INT | IDINT) OPERATORBOOL (INT | IDINT)
              | (STRING | IDSTR) '=' (STRING | IDSTR)
              ;

INT : [0-9]+;
STRING : '"' .*? '"';
IDINT : [a-zA-Z]+;
IDSTR : [a-zA-Z]+'$';
NL : '\n';
WS : [ \t\r]+ -> skip;
OPERATORMATH : '+' | '-' | '*' | '/';
OPERATORBOOL : '=' | '>' | '<' | '>=' | '<=';
```

I just need a grammar to run these expression:

```
PRINT "Your name"
INPUT name
PRINT "HELLO" name

a = 6
IF a > 3 THEN
PRINT a
a = a -1
END IF

WHILE b = 3
PRINT b
a = b
WEND
```

Comment: is '+'  wrong? (one or more)

Comment: looks totally ok, could you please show your real grammar rules?

Comment: @DAle of course i wrote below

Comment: Thanks! (But to do it properly, you need to include it in the question, not to add as an answer).

Comment: And what error message do you have with `PRINT "HEllo"` `b = a` example?

Comment: Yeah actually after `PRINT "HELLo"` it wont read as part of `IF` flow

Comment: @nooogii: does it parse without the PRINT? (IF .. THEN a = b ..)

Comment: @rici yes it is

Comment: i am checking grammar with ANTLRWorks

Answer (score 0):

My answer isn't exactly about the `|` alternatives, but please keep reading, because like you, I found implementation of if..else constructs in a BASIC-like language a real challenge to implement.  I found some good resources online. When I got it right, many, many problems disappeared all at once and it **just started to work**.  Please take a look at my grammar snip:

```
ifstmt
:   IF condition_block (ELSE IF condition_block)* (ELSE stmt_block)?
;

condition_block
:   expr stmt_block
;

stmt_block
:   OBRACE statement+ CBRACE
|   statement
;
```

And my implementation (in C# visitor pattern):

```
 public override MuValue VisitIfstmt(LISBASICParser.IfstmtContext context)
    {
        LISBASICParser.Condition_blockContext[] conditions = context.condition_block();
        bool evaluatedBlock = false;
        foreach (LISBASICParser.Condition_blockContext condition in conditions)
        {
            MuValue evaluated = Visit(condition.expr());
            if (evaluated.AsBoolean())
            {
                evaluatedBlock = true;
                Visit(condition.stmt_block());
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!evaluatedBlock && context.stmt_block() != null)
        {
            Visit(context.stmt_block());
        }
        return MuValue.Void;
    }
```

Much borrowed from Bart Kiers's excellent implementation of his Mu demonstration language. Lots of great ideas in that project of his.  It really showed me the light and this code I've shown handles `if` statements great, nested arbitrarily deep if you need that.  This is production code running a critical domain-specific language.